# SetWindowLong_WndProc_wrapper(self.hwnd, self.old_windProc) AttributeError: 'WM_PenProvider' object has no attribute 'hwnd'

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd, python-venv

In my project, there is a function that, upon entering a date and an ID number, verifies the corresponding data in my JSON file and showcases the information associated with the given input. If that information available it displays a dialog that the mentioned data exists, when the ok button is pressed in that dialog, I encounter an error when clicking the button.

following error : File "D:\my_pro\rehab_tracker\rehab\Lib\site-packages\kivy\input\providers\wm_pen.py", line 119, in stop
SetWindowLong_WndProc_wrapper(self.hwnd, self.old_windProc)
^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'WM_PenProvider' object has no attribute 'hwnd'

This same code works fine in macOS the issue is with the windows.

I tried updating both kivy and kivymd. but the issue still exists.

Comment: [\[SO\]: Welcome to Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
Check [\[SO\]: How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or
**[\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)**
for more asking related details. 
Also, [\[JonSkeet.CodeBlog\]: WRITING THE PERFECT QUESTION](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question) might be a good point to start.